# Struts2 ajax theme not working for in IE10

Tags: ajax, struts2, dojo, internet-explorer-10

We are developing a **struts 2** application, in that we are using **dojo ajax theme** to save and retrieve data.

This is working for all major browsers except for iE10. In IE10 the ajax request not at all get called.

Its simply showing empty space.

i have tried various combinations for ajax theme, but i could get the desired result!

In our application we are using struts 2.0.14 version

Comment: What did you try to make it working?

Comment: I strongly suggest: migrate to Struts 2.3.12 (i was using Struts 2.0.14 since 6 months ago, then our standard finally changed and I started migrating all the applications... a big application can be ported in less than 4 hours, a small one in less than 1 hour), and if not too expensive, leave dojo plugin for native dojo, or jquery plugin or native jquery. Dojo plugin is **deprecated** since years (since 2.1 version), the support will degrade in the future probably for other browsers too.

Comment: struts2 Ajax theme is based on DOJO and that too the earlier version and do not see any reason to be supported by modern version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When i seraching for a solution i came across this link

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/WW-3969?page=com.atlassian.streams.streams-jira-plugin:activity-stream-issue-tab

By this, Dojo plugin is deprecated, so there will not be an issue fix for IE-10 and we need to adopt/migrate for some other plugin/framework like **struts2-jquery plugin** for **ie10** usage.

i will work on this and update this answer with my findings/solutions.